# Checkout Add-to-Cart Returns to an Ajax Request URL Instead of Catalog Page

Tags: checkout, cart, catalog, ajax

Magento is redirecting the page to the last "URL request", meaning if the catalog page has an ajax call, it would return to that URL. Which is odd because after adding an item to the cart, it would display a JSON response which came from the last Ajax request made by the catalog page. My setting upon adding an item to the cart is to return to the catalog page instead of redirecting the user to the Cart page. Any idea?

Comment: Where to start... perhaps a rewrite issue. Are you showing any errors in your logs?

Comment: Apparently, none is showing in the logs related to it.

Comment: But, you do have error logging enabled?

Comment: Yes. Since I can view other logs.

Comment: Anyone knows about this issue?

Comment: I'm getting there. I have created an ajax call that builds the buttons because of some logic that I need to implement. Because of this from Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart: $routeParams = array(
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->_getHelperInstance('core')
                ->urlEncode($this->getCurrentUrl()),
            'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
        ); that's why the getCurrentUrl() returns the Ajax URL.

Comment: I am having the same problem with a ajax loaded add to cart button, did you ever solve it?

Comment: Yep @wlin, solved it by returning the previous URL. Using AJAX-build buttons, getCurrentUrl() returns the AJAX URL instead of the catalog page, which appears to be normal. See my last comment.